# Mergesort: getting java.lang.StackOverflowError for 100000 numbers but not for 10000

Tags: java, mergesort, stack-overflow

My code works fine for 10000 but not for 100000 numbers.

The error occurs at

```
result.add(next);
result.addAll(mergeInt(left,right));
```

Here's the code:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> mergeSortInt(ArrayList<Integer> array)
    {
        if (array.size() <= 1) return array;

        ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size() / 2; i++)
        {
            left.add(array.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = array.size() / 2; i < array.size(); i++) 
        {
            right.add(array.get(i));
        }

        return mergeInt(mergeSortInt(left), mergeSortInt(right));
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> mergeInt(ArrayList<Integer> left, ArrayList<Integer> right)
    {
        if (left.size() == 0) return right;
        if (right.size() == 0) return left;

        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int next;

        if (left.get(0) > right.get(0))
        {
            next = right.get(0);
            right.remove(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            next = left.get(0);
            left.remove(0);
        }

        result.add(next);
        result.addAll(mergeInt(left,right));

        return result;
    }
```

What exactly is a StackOverFlowError? And why does it only occur for a larger amount of numbers?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

I don't really see how this is a duplicate since I'm also asking for help specifically with my  code.

Comment: Method calls go on the stack. When you recurse to too deep a level, your _overflow_ your stack by trying to put too many things on it. It is similar (in an abstract way) to an infinite loop (or just a really long one) in code.

Comment: @JesanFafon - "When you *recur* too deeply ....".  Yes, this often leaves you cursing repeatedly, but that's another word entirely.

Answer (score 0):

A StackOverflowError occurs when you have too many stored method environments on the stack. When one function calls another function, it has to store its variables and state in a *stack frame*. When the call to the other function returns, the original function's frame is popped and used to restore the function's state.

Since mergesort is a recursive algorithm, `mergeInt` will push another frame to the stack with every recursive call to itself. Mergesort requires a depth of `log_2 n` recursive calls, where `n` is the length of the input. Therefore, when you increase `n`, you increase the number of stack frames that have to be created and stored. If there are too many of those, you will get a StackOverflowError.